# Appcelerator : BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *)

Tags: ios, appcelerator-titanium

This is the WARN that with the recent updates of Appcelerator appears in my console

```
[WARN] : 2016-04-05 14:51:01.391 App Name[5489:210793] BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: Is a directory
```

I don't find any information related to this WARN.For now does not seem to cause any problem, but i don't know what cause this.

---

**UPDATE**

I found what causes this warning

Code example

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : "white"
});


var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : 100,
    height : 100,
    backgroundImage : ""
});

var a = true;
setInterval(function(e){
    a = !a;
    view.backgroundImage = a ? "DefaultIcon.png" : "";
    Ti.API.info("*"+view.backgroundImage+"*");
},500);

win.add(view);
win.open();
```

When set a `backgroundImage = "";`. I added the `Ti.API.info` because without it the WARN doesn't appear

Comment: In my case UIImage initializing with contentsOfFile caused the problem. Changing it to UIImage(named: imageName) helped

Comment: Simon, could you elaborate how to do this with appcelerator?

Answer (score 1):

Because:
1. You are trying to load a file's data with a its path, but the path is pointing to a directory not a file.
2. Or, you are iterating all files in a directory, but there is another directory inside the directory path.